# Loading JSON into a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, json, gis, geojson, geopandas

I'm having difficulty loading the following JSON containing GIS data (https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/5rqd-h5ci.json) into a GeoDataFrame.

The following code fails when I try to set the geometry.

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
data = requests.get("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/5rqd-h5ci.json")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data.json())
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('the_geom')
gdf.head()
```

Comment: Note for future reference: this json file doesn't seem to be valid GeoJSON. For such files, you can much more easily use `geopandas.read_file(..)`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For people who are using web mapping libraries...

If the GeoJSON is wrapped in a `FeatureCollection`, as they often are when exported to a GeoJSON string by web mapping libraries (in my case, Leaflet), then all you need to do is pass the list at `features` to `from_features()` like so:

```
import geopandas as gpd
study_area = json.loads("""
 {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[36.394272, -18.626726], [36.394272, -18.558391], [36.489716, -18.558391], [36.489716, -18.626726], [36.394272, -18.626726]]]}}]}
""")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(study_area["features"])
print(gdf.head())
```

Output:

```
                                            geometry
0  POLYGON ((36.394272 -18.626726, 36.394272 -18....
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: That's a much better answer, especially for people that recently upgraded geopandas and faced a regression issue with former GeoDataFrame constructor

Comment: `.from_features` worked like a charm on a list of `features` as well.

Answer (score 23):

Setting the geometry fails because the `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` constructor doesn't appear to be built to handle JSON objects as python data structures. It therefore complains about the argument not being a valid geometry object. You have to parse it into something that `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` can understand, like a `shapely.geometry.shape`. Here's what ran without error on my side, Python 3.5.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape

r = requests.get("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/5rqd-h5ci.json")
r.raise_for_status()

data = r.json()
for d in data:
    d['the_geom'] = shape(d['the_geom'])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data).set_geometry('the_geom')
gdf.head()
```

A disclaimer: I know absolutely nothing about Geo anything. I didn't even know these libraries and this kind of data existed until I installed `geopandas` to tackle this bounty and read a little bit of online documentation.

Comment: Even cleaner:


`d['the_geom'] = d['the_geom'].apply(shape)`

Answer (score 3):

Combining the above answers, this worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape

nta = pd.read_json( r'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/93vf-i5bz.json' )
nta['the_geom'] = nta['the_geom'].apply(shape)
nta_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(nta).set_geometry('geometry')
```

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic way that uses regular dataframe functions inherited from `pandas`, and the native `GeoDataFrame.from_features`:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data.json())

# features column does not need to be stored, this is just for illustration
gdf['features'] = gdf['the_geom'].apply(lambda x: {'geometry': x, 'properties': {}})
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(gdf['features'])

gdf = gdf.set_geometry(gdf2.geometry)
gdf.head()
```